# Extract expected string in PieCloudDB

Tags: string

I want to output comma separated strings individually.

For example, this long string

```
'aa@test, bb@test, cc@test, dd@test'
```

I want to output `aa@test` or any one of the four string, anyway, I want to separate them.

By the way, If I want to output them into a table like below, is there a simple way to do that?

| Column |
| --- |
| aa@test |
| bb@test |
| cc@test |
| dd@test |

Answer (score 0):

In PieCloudDB, you can use `SPLIT_PART` function to split a string using a specified delimiter.

For example,

```
SELECT 
SPLIT_PART('aa@test,bb@test,cc@test,dd@test', ',',3)
```

It will output `cc@test`. You can specify the location of the string you want to output.

If you want to get a table, you can use `unnest` and `string_to_array`.

```
SELECT t as column
FROM unnest(string_to_array('aa@test,bb@test,cc@test,dd@test', ',')) AS t;
```

Output:

| column |
| --- |
| aa@test |
| bb@test |
| cc@test |
| dd@test |